# Query to define workink days from attendance

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a SQL query result :
[image]

Query :

```
SELECT  E.EMPID ,D.DT,to_char(D.DT,'Day') days ,case  
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'friday' then 'workday'
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'saturday' then 'workday'
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'monday' then 'workday' 
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'tuesday' then 'workday'
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'wednesday' then 'workday'
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'thursday' then 'workday' 
   else    'holiday' end work_days 
         
        ,D.DT+DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,0.25/24)+ ((H.FHR+(H.FMT/60)+DECODE(H.FAM,'PM',12,0))/24) INTIME,
         D.DT+DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,0.25/24)+ ((H.THR+(H.TMT/60)+DECODE(H.TAM,'PM',12,0))/24) OUTTIME
        ,E.ROWID  
  FROM EMP_SHIFT H, EMPL E,
           (SELECT LEVEL LVL , (TO_DATE('01-Dec-22','DD-MON-RR')+LEVEL-1) DT 
           FROM DUAL conNect by level  <= to_date('31-dec-22','DD-MON-RRRR')-TO_DATE('01-Dec-22','DD-MON-RRRR') +1 ) D
           WHERE E.SHIFT = H.CD
```

I need to get null yellow highlighed cells like the image below
[image]

Comment: Please review and improve your question. 1) Remove the images/links from your question, 2) Add both sample input data and expected outcome as tables in your question, 3) Explain what exactly you want to know. "I need" is no question or description. 4) Don't use unnecessary upper case, that's read as shouting/unkind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
SELECT  E.EMPID ,D.DT,to_char(D.DT,'Day') days ,case  
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'friday' then 'workday'
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'saturday' then 'workday'
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'monday' then 'workday' 
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'tuesday' then 'workday'
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'wednesday' then 'workday'
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') = 'thursday' then 'workday' 
   else    'holiday' end work_days ,
case  
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'friday' 
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'saturday' 
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'monday'  
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'tuesday' 
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'wednesday'
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'thursday' then NULL 
   else D.DT+DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,0.25/24)+ ((H.FHR+(H.FMT/60)+DECODE(H.FAM,'PM',12,0))/24) end INTIME,
case  
         when to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'friday' 
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'saturday' 
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'monday'  
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'tuesday' 
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'wednesday'
         or to_char(D.DT, 'fmday') != 'thursday' then NULL 
   else D.DT+DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,0.25/24)+ ((H.THR+(H.TMT/60)+DECODE(H.TAM,'PM',12,0))/24) end OUTTIME 
,E.ROWID  
  FROM EMP_SHIFT H, EMPL E,
           (SELECT LEVEL LVL , (TO_DATE('01-Dec-22','DD-MON-RR')+LEVEL-1) DT 
           FROM DUAL conNect by level  <= to_date('31-dec-22','DD-MON-RRRR')-TO_DATE('01-Dec-22','DD-MON-RRRR') +1 ) D
           WHERE E.SHIFT = H.CD
```

Comment: Which purpose should all these case when's have? Checking whether a day is a workday or not can be written much shorter.

Comment: Dear sir, thank you for my help. I solve the problem with helping of your suggestion